# Erlang Message Passing for Large Binaries, Optimizing Performance Recommendations

Tags: erlang

Ok, here's the question I've been thinking about today (which I'll test next week if I don't get an answer before hand).

I have a number of Erlang processes that I need to pass large binaries between. What I had been doing is using gproc:send to locate and send the binary to the appropriate process. However, I'm not sending only a binary, I'm typically sending a tuple such as "{self(),atom, Msg\binary}". At first I was thinking that this would be sufficient to meet the requirements for message processing of large binaries to avoid memory copy operations.

### 8.2  Process messages

> All data in messages between Erlang processes is copied, with the exception >of refc binaries on the same Erlang node.

From:[Erlang Efficiency Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html#id66069)

Now however, I'm starting to wonder, if the Message processor/compiler/etc going to understand there's a >64k binary in there? Or will it see the tuple and just think, let's copy the whole thing to the other process? Like I indicated I do plan on testing this next week to see and I'll gladly update the post with my findings.

I am using R16B03-1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Binaries greater than or equal to 64 bytes in size are stored in a shared area and are reference-counted, and so they are not copied between processes; only references to them are copied.

Comment: Thanks Steve, so to confirm, it doesn't matter if the large binary is part of a tuple or not?

Comment: @OldSchool Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples don't actually contain their elements but rather pointers to them. So every value inside a tuple is also copied when the tuple is. Big (>64) and small binaries have different types underneath even though for a user they seem alike. Therfore VM can use different copy operations.